# Arthropods That Bond

Tags: insects, bonding, domestication

I like arthropods a lot and enjoy keeping them, but most seem to be indifferent to humans or hate them, so are their any species of pet arthropods that enjoy interacting with humans and will bond with humans?

Comment: Distantly related: [Are there native web building spiders in North America that can be domesticated?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5919)