# Reptiles or other critters for insect control in a greenhouse?

Tags: reptiles, pest-control

I'm looking at building a 15 ft wide x 40 ft long (4.5 x 12 m) glass solarium / conservatory (same thing, called differently depending on where you live). This will be used about 90% for raising vegetables and about 10% as a place to sit and relax.

I plan on using zero pesticides / insecticides and I'm looking at alternative methods of preventing damage from insect infestations. What are some animals that I could "release" into the solarium that would control pests but not damage the vegetables too much?

My roommates have a bearded dragon, and overall I quite like reptiles, so snakes or lizards might be a good fit, but I'd consider other critters as well. There might be hanging rows of plants as well as plants on tables, so something that could climb or fly would probably be good. I can provide additional feed and care to the critters if necessary, but ideally I'm trying to make this like micro-ecosystem and be mostly self-sustaining.

Answer (score 1):

The root of the problem here is that if you can't keep insects out of your greenhouse, you can't keep out the insects that have been poisoned by your neighbors and/or the plant supplier, but have not died yet.  As outlined in the answers at [Can I use a gecko to get rid of a cockroach infestation?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1788) if you feed poisoned insects to your reptile your reptile will be poisoned.

There are a couple of really good answers to this question [What is the best way to grow vegetables without using chemical insecticide?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2150) on our sister site on Gardening.

If you have a interest in creating a sealed, self contained ecosystem [Space.SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/) & [Biology.SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/) would be good resources