# Can I feed wild Aphids to my Fire Bellied Newt

Tags: diet, amphibians

I've had a [Fire Bellied Newt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_fire_belly_newt) for going on 10 years now.  I've fed her all sorts of frozen and packaged food, she prefers blood-worm.

I've recently had an [Aphid problem with my pumpkin patch](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/35076/what-are-the-black-creatures-on-my-pumpkin-leaves) and while reading about them I came across the fact that they are favoured by Newts.  I know that Newts are pretty sensitive so would it be safe to offer these pests as snacks for my Newt and give her something more interesting in her diet or is the risk of contamination/contraction too high?

[This](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10329/feeding-leopard-gecko-food-from-outside) question would suggest not but I've found references from [articles](http://blogs.thatpetplace.com/thatreptileblog/2009/08/17/wild-caught-invertebrates-as-reptile-and-amphibian-food-pesticide-concerns-part-1/#.WZrWECiGOiM) and zoos which state it's generally pretty safe.  Specifically though, Aphids CAN be the target of pesticides although my personal garden has none and is pretty secluded from public areas.  Is there even a way I can make this safer?

Comment: Rethinking.... Because aphids don't fly (actually some do but assuming you only capture non-flying ones), the sphere of influence you would need to control might be much less.  A quick look on google did not get me how far the non-flying ones might travel.

Comment: It's tough, as my garden is in a separated housing block.  Surrounded on all sides by 5 story houses in a populated area and I seem to have Black Bean Aphids, which come in flying (they don't look like these though) and non flying varieties.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_bean_aphid

Is is a very similar question to be fair.